# Prism Template Pack in VS2022, unable to choose .net framework

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, visual-studio-2022, .net-framework-version

I try to create Prism(WPF) using Prism Template Pack, which version is 2.4.1

[click to see Prism Template Pack version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyH4B.png)

However, I can't choose .net framework to create new project.

[click to see project create 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSdJZ.png)

[click to see project create 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrrPV.png)

What should I do to create .net framework 4.x Prism(WPF) project?

Comment: If you create one of the WPF projects, what are your options for framework target? The documentation doesn't actually say anything on that subject.

Comment: If I use Prism Blank App to create project, it will direct to .net 6 automatically, and I can‘t change it back to .net framework. I want create desktop app that can work on other's PC, if there PC don't have .net core or later version, they need to install that first, it may cause trouble. Fortunately, most computer have .net framework.

Comment: Do you have .net 4.8 on your pc?

Comment: Yes, SDK 4.8.1 and 4.7.2

Comment: I suspect that Prism has been updated to only support .NET Core. It definitely used to support .NET Framework but, as that's pretty much on the way out, the developer probably decided that supporting .NET Core was more important and supporting both was a waste of resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can always build with the Prism Blank App and edit the csproj file an set

```
  <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
```

Its works.